# How to overlap a line with a label in Plotly graph_objects.Scatter()?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I'm trying to create a graph with three lines on it, making labels for each marker.
The problem is that on the chart there may be such points of intersection of lines and labels that the labels will be overlapped by the lines.
Is it possible to set something like a z-index so that the caption text overlaps the lines?

Tried to create figure with three scatters, lines overlapping text:

[image: overlap]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.